# Search bar like google android

Tags: android, material-design

I need to create a search bar in my application similar like

http://cdn.gsmarena.com/pics/15/02/play-search-update/gsmarena_002.gif

Is there any library available for this.

Answer (score 2):

try :
https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch

I didn't try it but it seems to be the library you are looking for and furthermore easy to use.

Cheers.

Comment: Please do not answer and encourage off-topic questions, such as the one asking for external tools or libraries. it makes it look like it's okay to ask such questions, and it will probably end up closed and deleted (and your work will be for naught).